# Access OAuth2 Protected api from the Java Batch Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices

I have Springboot Microservice app comprises( Discovery , Eureka Client , Zulu Proxy , Gateway )which is configured with OAUTH2 which is working fine. 
and OAUTH2 is configured as the in memory token store. i have rest end points gateway exposed

ex :

> localhost:8080/hello/gateway

now i have java batch , which will call micro service app gateway example (above api) to get the required response. since that is protected with OAUTH2 i cant access api directly.

- **is there a way to access the api without token or can we bypass the authorization logic by passing the hardcoded token from batch and validating in the Gateway**
- **Tried to create a non-expiring token but since its in-memory token, it will not work after the api restart**
- Tired to create a custom filter and  but it didnt work as expected . below is my resource server code.

> ```
> @EnableResourceServer
> public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
>
> private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";
>
> @Autowired
> private AppProperties appProperties;
>
> @Override
> public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
>     resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>
>         http.
>                 anonymous().disable()
>                 .authorizeRequests()
>                 .antMatchers("/testService/**").authenticated()
>                 .and()
>                 //.addFilterBefore(new BatchCustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
>                 .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
>
>
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Let me if know there is any good way of doing this ,  Suggestions are highly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

yes had overridden **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** configure method to ignore the specific endpoint.

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/testService/testApi/**");
}
```

Now im able to access Api from batch after ignoring the endpoint from web security.